# How do I know how much a kWh costs me if I have my private generator

Tags: generator, efficiency, cost

I have a 10 kVA generator and its efficiency is approx. 90%
How can I know the cost of a kWh?
Estimate the price of diesel as $2.5 a liter.

Comment: So you only need to know how much your generator consumes fuel to make some amount of energy. We don't know that. Or rather, do you simply want to know how much energy one liter of diesel has?

Comment: 90% seems suspiciously high for any sort of engine-generator setup.

Comment: what do you think is the general efficiecy?

Comment: From Joules to watts...20%?

Comment: A good check is to purchase a plug in power meter to measure your electrical consumption while logging how much diesel you use. Then you can work out your actual efficiency - and if this doesn't match the theoretical consumption as described in the answers below then you might want to investigate why

Comment: If the generator is running for some hours to some days you should look at your electricity meter and write down the displayed value at the begin and end of the chosen time interval. You also need to know how much fuel was in the tank at these two moments. You calculate the generated energy in kWh and the consumed diesel in liters. The used diesel volume is multiplied with 2.5, the result is divided by the kWh value and you get the cost of a kWh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a 10 kVA generator and its efficiency is approx. 90%.

That's impossible. No internal combustion engine can achieve that. The maximum **theoretical** value is 75%. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_engine#:%7E:text=cycle%20is%20positive.-,Efficiency,a%20diesel%20engine%20is%2075%25.).

For a small generator you'd be lucky to get 40%.

The 90% may refer to the **alternator efficiency** and this is in the realms of possibility (as is the likelihood that this number was advertised to mislead the buyer).

> How can I know the cost of a kWh?
> Estimate the price of diesel as $2.5 a liter.

Assuming a resistive load so that 10 kVA = 10 kW<sup>1</sup> then the mechanical input will be given by $$ \frac {P_{out}}{e_{alt} \times e_{eng}} = \frac{10} {0.9 \times 0.4} = 28 \ \text {kW} $$

Diesel has an energy density close to 10 kWh/L so you will need 2.8 L/hour for 10 kW output.

2.8 L × $2.5 = $7 for 10 kWh.

1 kWh = $7 / 10 = $0.70.

---

<sup>1</sup> Most generators are designed to run at a power factor less than unity - maybe 0.8 or so. As a result further derating may be required in your use case.

Comment: Also, most generators are designed to run in the range of ~30-80% output power.  Operation outside this range will incur a drop in efficiency that could range from trifling to ludicrous.

Answer (score 1):

There are roughly 38 MJ or 10kWh in a liter of diesel (Google it). If diesel costs $2.50 per liter that means you get 10kWh for $2.50 which is 1kWh for $0.25. Since it's only 90% efficient you actually get 0.9kWh for $0.25 which is 1kWh for $0.27777... (round to $0.28 if you like).

However, your generator isn't 90% efficient. More like 20-40%.

The size of the generator is irrelevant, except insofar as it affects the efficiency. A bigger generator uses more fuel just to keep itself going.

Answer (score 0):

The energy density of diesel is 9.6 kilowatt hours per liter. The efficiency of a small diesel generator is 25-35%, so you can get 2.4kWh to 3.36kWh of energy out of the diesel.

However, this only applies if the generator is working in the optimum speed range and the energy is also being effectively consumed. If the generator runs without a consumer connected, or only a very small one, like a mobile phone charger, then the efficiency drops to zero.

- At 25% efficiency, 1kWh costs $2.5/((9.6kWh)*0.25%)=1.04€/kWh
- At 35% efficiency, 1kWh costs $2.5/((9.6kWh)*0.35%)=0.74€/kWh
- At 90% efficiency, 1kWh costs $2.5/((9.6kWh)*0.9%)=0.29€/kWh